# Angle bisector of $a(x-1)^2+2h(x-1)(y-1)+b(y-2)^2=0$

Tags: geometry

One of the bisector of the angle between the line $$a(x-1)^2+2h(x-1)(y-1)+b(y-2)^2=0$$ is $$x+2y-5=0$$ and $$\frac{b-a}{h} =\frac{p}{q}$$, where $p$ and $q$  are co-prime  then find the value of $p+q$

Comment: Replace $x$ with $5-2y$ in  the given quadratic equation to find $y=2$ or $=?$

Comment: How does $\frac{b - a}{h} = \frac{p}{q}$ become a line? There's no $x$ or $y$ in it.

Comment: This is not the equation of a pair of lines. You need either $y-1$ in the last term or $y-2$ in the middle term.

Comment: @Samar Imam Zaidi Can you please notify whether my answer is correct or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think there must have been $(y-2)$ instead of $(y-1)$
Solution:

On simplifying the given expression we get

$$ax^2+by^2+2hxy-2ax.........=0 $$
And you might know that the only terms of $x^2, y^2$ and the $xy$ term gives the slopes of the lines. So I will consider the first three terms.
$$ax^2+ 2hxy+ by^2 $$
On dividing the all three terms by $x^2$ we get a quadratic in $m$ where the roots of this quadratic are the slopes of this line. ( I represent $\frac{y}{x}= m$)

$$bm^2+ 2hm +a........   Equation (1)$$
The angle bisector makes equal angles with pair of lines and slope of given bisector is $\frac{-1}{2}$
Hence

$$\frac{m_1+\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{m_1}{2}} = \frac{\frac{-1}{2}-m_2}{1-\frac{m_2}{2}} $$

where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the slopes of given pair of lines
On simplifying this we get $$4m_1m_2-3(m_1+m_2)-4=0$$
 By Vieta's rule on equation 1 we have 
$$m_1m_2=\frac{a}{b} $$and 
$$m_1+m_2=\frac{-2h}{b}$$

On substituting this in obtained equation the equation simplifies to$$ 2(b-a)=3h. $$

Therefore we arrive at the answer which is $ p=3 $and $q=2$ hence $$p+q=5$$